# Couldn't mark volume as bootable in hpacucli (SmartArray P400i)

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, hpe

I've got HP **ProLiant G5** with hardware controller HP **SmartArray P400i**. I created logical drive from 4 HDD and installed OS, but i don't know hot to mark this volume as boot. Here's the output of `hpacucli` in HP SSA disk:

```
=> ctrl slot=0 modify bootcontroller=enable  
=> ctrl slot=0 id 1 modify bootvolume=primary  
Error: logicaldrive 1 cannot be set as the boot volume.  
Error: This operation is not supported with the current configuration. Use the "show" command on devices to show additional details about the configuration.  
Reason: Not Appllicable

=> ctrl slot=0 show config  
Smart Array P400i in Slot 0 (Embedded) (sn: xxxxxxxxxx)  
Array A (SATA, Unused Space: 0MB)  
logicaldrive 1 (1.8 TB, RAID 1+0, OK)  
physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 1 TB, OK)  
physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 1 TB, OK)  
physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 1 TB, OK)  
physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA, 1 TB, OK)
```

Also, logical drive type is `Data`.
What is wrong could be here? How can i mark logical volume as bootable?

Comment: What OS are you using? Is there a problem? It's not common to need to mark a logicaldrive as bootable.

Comment: I think. It is because you've assigned only one logical volume. By default HP smart RAID boot from first created logical volume.

Comment: @ewwhite CentOS. I thought the problem in OS bootloader too, but after re-installing grub2 and checking it in `xxd /dev/...` i have no doubt in that.

Comment: @kamish did you see `GRUB` on monitor? If yes, the problem is Centos. If no, the problem is RAID controller.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy I didn't saw grub even in emergency mode but _if I did, I wouldn't write here =)_   
Also, even with two logical drives there was no boot menus.

Comment: @kamish Before all update BIOS, then update RAID firmware, then restore Centos boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I downloaded [Smart Update Firmware DVD](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=1156881&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4103) and updated everything what it suggested. And now I see that `Select Boot Volume` button!

Answer (score 1):

It seems it should be possible from BIOS Option ROM Configuration for Arrays (ORCA).

h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3454575&docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c04135224

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, i have no this option in array menu =( tomorrow i'll try to upgrade SmartArray firmware up to 7.24, maybe it could help...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as shown in the picture above No "Select Boot Volume". I've flashed the P400 to the 7.24 version using CP017698.scexe, and still did not see the option. I downloaded the hpssaoffline-1.50-4.0-x86.zip (no contract needed) and used the ACU (selecting the P400) and was able to use the boot selection there to change the boot drive there.